# Concerning struct type stat and system call functions like S_ISREG

Tags: gdb, stat

So I'm trying to understand built-in functions such as S_ISREG , S_IXUSR , etc. I'm having trouble understanding what functions like these return or what do they do in general and how do they work with system calls like **stat** which is (from what i've read) a system struct.

Awesome, cool. But what I don't understand is what do these variables or functions return? I read that they both mutually help one another, but what *output* does the `st->st_mode` return that makes it valid for the function `S_ISREG` to take in?

To sum it all up:

**What do functions like S_ISREG receive and what do they return? And what does the struct type stat contains that makes it validated for S_ISREG to use?**

PS: I found this function below and I just want to understand it better. If you want to explain this along with the function below, even better.

```
static int
    valid_cgi_script(struct stat *st)
    {
        if (!S_ISREG(st->st_mode))
            return 0;

        if (!(st->st_mode & S_IXUSR))
            return 0;

        if (cgi_uid >= 0 && cgi_gid >= 0) {
            if (st->st_uid != cgi_uid || st->st_gid != cgi_gid)
                return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> What do functions like S_ISREG receive and what do they return?

The `S_ISREG` is not a function on most libc implementations, but a macro. You can look for its definition in `/usr/include` (or wherever your system headers are installed):

```
grep -r S_ISREG /usr/include
```

Indeed the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) says "The following macros shall be provided to test whether a file is of the specified type.", though I don't believe it is the *intention* of the standard to say that `S_ISREG` must be a macro.

The macro receives an integer `st_mode` and yields an integer which is `0` if the file is not a regular file, and non-zero if it is.

```
static int
valid_cgi_script(struct stat *st)
{
    if (!S_ISREG(st->st_mode))
```

If the file is not a regular file, return 0 (false).

```
        return 0;

    if (!(st->st_mode & S_IXUSR))
```

If the file is not executable by the user who owns the file, return 0.

```
        return 0;

    if (cgi_uid >= 0 && cgi_gid >= 0) {
        if (st->st_uid != cgi_uid || st->st_gid != cgi_gid)
```

If `cgi_uid` and `cgi_gid` global variables are set, and the file's owner or group do not match them, return 0.

```
            return 0;
    }
```

Otherwise, return 1 (true).

```
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Well the grep -r S_ISREG /usr/include part definitely helped me out, I can see the definition in the header. Now I need to understand how macros work, but I have only worked with them like

#define NUM 3

and that's it.
But what I'm seeing is this:

#define S_ISREG(mode)    __S_ISTYPE((mode), __S_IFREG)

trying to figure out how these definitions work